# SendInput: Combine Unicode and VirtualKey

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to replay remote characters on a local machine. It seems I can only use SendInput to either send Unicode chars or VirtualKeys... But I need both. I do not know which of them an application needs. Games need virtual codes, but sometimes unicode (for chat), etc...

So how can I replay key input such that the end result is still the unicode char that I got from the remote end, but also transmits the virtual codes for apps that need it?

I was thinking of:

```
SendInput(virtualKey, DOWN)
SendInput(unicode, DOWN)
SendInput(unicode, UP)
SendInput(virtualKey, UP)
```

But I tried various combinations and always ended up with duplicated chars.

Comment: You get duplicated chars because the `TranslateMessage()` function in the message loop is what's responsible for turning your standard `WM_KEYDOWN` messages (produced by your `SendInput()` of the virtual-key codes) into `WM_CHAR` messages (which is what things like the edit control use to get actual characters). Can you provide an example of a sequence you want to send out?

Comment: Actually most of the "standard" chars will work without unicode. The only problem I found so far is "Caps Lock" which is not transmitted as a keypress at all, thus I get uppercase without receiving a shift, thus I emulate the wrong char atm. This could be fixed fairly easy still but I bet there are more subtle issues out in the wild if I skip this unicode forwarding

Comment: Why don't you use automation